# Natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let M be the set of those natural number that can be written using only 0's and 1's ( in the decimal system). Prove that,for every natural number k, there exists a number m belongs to M such that.
(1) m has exactly k 1's, and 
(2) m is divisible by k .
(For example , if k=3, then the number 101010 belongs to M is divisble by 3.

Comment: Hint: Consider specifically numbers of the form $111\ldots 1000\ldots 0$.

Comment: This question has been asked several times, will try and dig out a recent occurrence.